# StyleBundle IncludeDirectory can not match some files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

some css files I can not include them into my head tag to use StyleBundle IncludeDirectory their name ends with min.css why?

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/css", "*.css"));
```

[problem](http://postimg.org/image/qgex9mgd7/)

Comment: You are in debug mode or release mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc provided by Microsoft

> Note: Unless EnableOptimizations is true or the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config file is set to false, files will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the .min version of files will not be used,  the full debug versions will be selected. EnableOptimizations  overrides the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config file

Read [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

So in debug mode, I think you should have non-min versions of your css files.